# idiom to choose between two values

Tags: scala, language-features

Is there an idiom in Scala to simplify the following pattern?

```
          if (some_comparison(a, b)) a else b
```

The problem is that the repeating `a` & `b` seem redundant.

One of the joys of learning Scala (and functional languages generally) is discovering the elegant ways to do things. So I would not surprise me if the above code could be rewritten *something* like:

```
    choose(a, b, some_comparison)
```

where `choose` is a built-in operator.

I could write `choose` myself, but I was wondering if there was a similar feature  native to the language.

Comment: Maybe `Either.cond`, but if-else is fine imo.

Comment: Agree with @MarioGalic just minor addition: Scala does not have Java/JS like ternary operator, so this if-else totally fine.

Comment: @IvanKurchenko I wasn't looking for a ternary operator. The ternary does not solve the problem as a & b are still 'evaluated' twice;  some_comparison(a, b):a?b

Comment: @Ken so `a` & `b` are actuall `def`'s ? You did not mentioned this, I thought they are just values.

Comment: @IvanKurchenko No. I was thinking about values. I put the 'evaluated' in quotes to try to acknowledge that. If/else is fine, it works, but, critically, for me, it's not *elegant*

Comment: @MarioGalic I'm sure I am misunderstanding, but `Either.cond` doesn't address the core of the question. I would have to write `Either.cond(some_comparison(a, b), a, b)`, which still leave the redundancy problem of repeating a & b in the expression.

Comment: Is something like this more elegant? :) `Seq("ab", "abcd").sortWith(_.length > _.length).head`

Comment: @det0 With that approach you could also use `Seq(a, b).min(Ordering.fromLessThan(some_comparison))`

Comment: @det0 is is uglier than else/if, but feels somehow more idiomatic. For my example it would look like:  `Seq(a,b).sortWith(someComparison).head`